# Did Tesla's device actually clone Angier?

Tags: the-prestige

In the movie *The Prestige*, how does Tesla's device create exact, real copies of anybody or anything?

Moreover, each time Angier did his show, did he know that he was a duplicate and the real was somewhere else? Hidden? Or did each time the real die and the duplicate lived?

Comment: Since the device doesn't actually exist in reality (and frankly, is likely not possible at all), we can't really say *how* it achieves what it does. ;-) However, thinking about real and duplicate really makes no sense here. Angier always died in each and every show yet he also survived all the shows. That is the beauty of a true duplication machine.

Comment: I also got the idea that, while they are referred to as "clones", they are not biological duplicates, but the exact same persons. The underlying idea, AFAIR, is that they are somehow brought to what we in contemporary parlance call "this timeline" from their original timelines.

Comment: Your second question is directly answered by voice-over in the film (if you trust the narration).

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the site.  I do think this question is a duplicate of the one suggested.  If you think this is incorrect, please let us know.